# How to retrieve data from Mongo DB via node js in the same order as in Model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I am trying to get data from mongoDB but the unwanted data are coming at the top , it is not in the order as i have added in the Mongoose schema .

**Category schema :**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type:String,required: true},
    image: { type:String,required: true},
    descriptions: String,
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    updatedAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    isEnabled: { type: Boolean, default: true },
    isDeleted: { type: Boolean, default: false },
})

const Category = mongoose.model('Category',categorySchema)

module.exports.Category =  Category;
```

**Response:**

```
{
            "isEnabled": true,
            "isDeleted": false,
            "_id": "60fac324c9edd53244e5cc5e",
            "name": "Cold Drinks",
            "image": "http://localhost:5000/icons/breakfast.png",
            "descriptions": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. .",
            "createdAt": "2021-07-23T13:24:52.091Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-07-23T13:24:52.091Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
```

i want to get the name , image , description at top  as it is schema .

As we all know the order doesn't matter in `Dictionary` but i am curious to know , is there any way to return the object in the same order .

i need the send all Category data to front end ,i can't just select name , image and description.
Please help me

Comment: but for what reason? you can still query them just fine and i've never came across an database model where the order is important.

Comment: Yes , i agree  when we have hash map we don't need in order , we can access all the data @KakSarkar . No problem , But we want to keep the same model in front end also iOS and Android .